# Context switch in CPU

Tags: multithreading

suppose the time it takes  to switch between user and kernel modes is t1 and to switch between two processes is t2.Which is greater t1 or t2?

Comment: Homework? If it is, please be up front about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically it depends on the platform. In practice, a switch from one process to another typically goes from the original process to kernel mode, then the kernel decides which process to schedule next, then there's a switch from kernel mode to user mode running the second process.

As such, switching from one process to another *includes* a switch from user- to kernel-mode, plus more, so it'll be slower.

Answer (score 4):

I think t2 is always larger, because process switch happens via kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  You should profile yours.

Comment: You might try making a simple system call in a loop and seeing how fast that is.  Then run a program which calls `sched_yield()` a lot and see how that goes (how much time until it gets control back).  I think you could learn something this way, with some refinements.  That said, your answer about t2 being longer in general seems intuitively sensible.